# Bootstrap modal, strange behavior (duplicate informations)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Laravel 5.5, Bootstrap 3.7 and jQuery.

When I open the modal and close it directly, then when I do an action in the modal it performs two times the opening function.

If I open and close it (directly) three times, then when I do an action in the modal it performs four times the opening function.

Finnaly, if I open and close it (directly) X times, then when I do an action in the modal it performs X+1 times the opening function.

It performs the function for all the old openings and for the last opening.

**HTML :**

```
@foreach(... as $seance)

    ...

            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-primary bouton-reservation" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservationModal-{{ $seance->id_seance }}"</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade reservationModal" id="reservationModal-{{ $seance->id_seance }}" data-seance='{{ $seance->id_seance }}' role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reservationModal-{{ $seance->id_seance }}" aria-hidden="true">

        // modal content with a form.

    </div>
@endforeach
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    ...

    $(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '.reservationModal', function (e) {
        // JS content
    });

    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.reservationModal', function(e) {
        // JS content
    });
});
```

I hope the problem is explained quite clearly ...

The problem can not come from the fact that I use `$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#reservationModal', function (e) {` instead of `$('#reservationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {`?

**Exemple**

[image]

On this exemple, I close 2 times the modal, and when I choose `Nico` on the `select` after a third opening, my JS append 3 times my data.

`Append` starts when I click on the button `Ajouter`, however, I only click once and not three.

Futhermore, when I delete the info with the X on the right side, all info disappears.

Thank's for help !

Comment: How do you show/open the modal?

Comment: I show the modal with a `<button>` (I updated my question). And I close it when I click on a button or outside of the modal window. I didn't write this, it's a bootstrap management.

Comment: Don't think this will fix your issue but `aria-labelledby` should point to the ID of the button that opens your modal. In your example you do not have an ID on the button.

Comment: Is you JavaScript contained any any other JavaScript structure?

Comment: What do you mean by JavaScript structure ?

Comment: forEach or $.each ... programming structure.

Comment: On my JS file I don't have loops, juste some `ajax` calls but they are used after button click.

Comment: Try putting your JavaScript for `shown/hidden.bs.modal` in a [jQuery document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: They already are in a jQuery `document.ready`. I updated my question.

Comment: I see no reason you would be getting this behavior from the example you gave. I think we would need a larger example. But before you do that maybe you should try to track down what your code is doing. For this I often put several `console.log("##");` messages with different numbers in each and see if something seem out of order or unexpected.

Comment: Thank's for help, I will try to put more `console.log` to understand why it executes the code several times, even if I already did it ...

Comment: I see you are using x number of modals for x number of reservations. Why not use 1 modal and change content & behavior based on whatever is selected after button click? This might be good solution and could solve the problem you're having.

Comment: @RehbanKhatri because I have several reservations. It is possible to use one modal but change the content according to the data of the `foreach`?

Comment: @RehbanKhatri the good way is to create a empty modal, and fill it with JS when I click on the button ?

Comment: Why not?. You're using Id `$seance->id_seance` and I assume it is unique. Say you have a variable `selectedReservation` which is bind with the modal. On click of button you change it's value to the one that is clicked.

Comment: I can try this yes, it would make more sense. The only question I ask myself is how to store the `id` of the selected `seance`? Can I use `data-...` attribute on the button used to display the modal?

Comment: When I use one modal, the problem is the same. However, the problem can not come from the fact that I use `$(document).on('shown.bs.modal', '#reservationModal', function (e) {` instead of `$('#reservationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {`?